# Can anyone suggest me some resources for studying about the different types of cryogenic valves and their design aspects

Tags: cryogenics

Book titles, videos, articles or any other resource that I could refer

Comment: Hi Sangeeth, our site is not really intended to be a broad scope literature request service. If you have a narrower question about cryogenic valves, you can edit your question and we might be able to answer it.